# change python indent in a specific file

Tags: indentation, python, tabs

I have a piece of legacy code in Python that uses inconsistent tabs - 2 spaces in some instances and 4 in others.  I have my defaults set in my .emacs file to use 4 spaces, but in this case emacs finds the inconsistent spacing and uses a tab width of 2.

I'm working to update the file in other ways, and I'd like to set the tab width, in this specific file, to 4.  How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One method of setting variables on a per-file basis is to write a local variable specification in the first line of the file.  The details for doing this are in [§48.2.4.1 ‘Specifying File Variables’ of the Emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables).

A local variable specification takes the following form:

```
-*- mode: MODENAME; VAR: VALUE; ... -*-
```

You can repeat `VAR: VALUE;` for as many variables as you want to set.

Assuming you are using `python-mode`, you need to set the variable `python-indent-offset` to 4.  Don’t forget to comment out the specification so that the Python interpreter doesn’t attempt to parse it:

```
# -*- mode: python-mode; python-indent-offset: 4 -*-
```

You can do this by hand, or use <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> `add-file-local-variable-prop-line` and Emacs will prompt you for a variable and its value.  It will also take care of commenting out the specification.

Comment: Great!  Note that you must restart emacs for this to take effect (or reload the file somehow).

Comment: That’s a consideration I perhaps should have mentioned. You can use `M-x revert-buffer` to reload the file.

Comment: I had to specify `mode: Python` instead of `mode: python-mode`.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you can't.

Consider this piece of code.

```
x = 0
if True:
    x += 1
  x += 2
```

You can't programmatically decide if that block should become this

```
x = 0
if True:
    x += 1
    x += 2
```

or this

```
x = 0
if True:
    x += 1
x += 2
```

It's almost impossible to fix inconsistent spaces with a program.

However you can write a simple function to change indentation level of file, say all 2 spaces can be converted to 4 spaces.

I faced the [exact problem a year back](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/issues/565). I just indented entire file to 4 spaces using `M-x indent-region`. After that I have manually fixed lines which are incorrectly indented.

Answer (score 0):

For switching to tab character for indents, put the following at the top of your file:

```
# -*- mode: python-mode; indent-tabs-mode: t -*-
```